# Can not use clipping option when rendering with transparency

Tags: matlab

I am currently working with annotating images in MATLAB. To mark one spesific point along an axes, I am plotting points with clipping off to be able to draw outside the axes limits. However, if I include a patch object and make it transparent, that is, I implicitly change the renderer from 'painters' to 'OpenGL', the object drawn with clipping off disappears from the figure.

See example code and images below.

Any ideas on workaround or better implementations? I want the best of both worlds!

```
f1 = figure(1);clf
set(f1,'RendererMode','auto')   %# Make sure renderer can change

%Plot objects
pLine = plot(0:0.1:1,0:0.1:1);hold on;
pointInside = plot(0.5,0.5,'v');
pointOutside=plot(0.5,1.01,'v','clipping','off'); %# Visible outside axes by clipping off.
patchHandle =patch([0.2;0.8;0.8;0.2],[0.2;0.2;0.8;0.8],ones(4,1));
patchHandle2 = patch([0.1;0.3;0.3;0.1],[0.7;0.7;0.9;0.9],zeros(4,1)); 
uistack(patchHandle2,'bottom')

axis([0 1 0 1])
colormap(summer)

%# Point outside now visible.

disp(get(f1,'renderer'))

%Make patch semi transparent
uistack(patchHandle,'top')          %# Patch goes over line and point
set(patchHandle,'facealpha',0.7);   %# Point and line visible again due to alpha

disp(get(f1,'renderer'))

%# Renderer has now changed and point outside no longer visible
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: OpenGL support in Matlab isn't great. As soon as you start to use transparency weird stuff starts happening.  If you simply want to make nice figures for a presentation/paper/etc... use plot2svg to export the figure and tweak using a vector graphics program.

Comment: Having the same issue bump!